# How to display the values in columns in Google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I got the output as below (row wise):

```
one
two
three
```

But I would like to display the value as below (column wise, single value in each cell):

```
one two three
```

Can any one please tell me how can I achieve this using `getRange` function in Google app script ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are setting only 1 value, I recommend using `getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols)` together with `Range` class methods `getValues()` and `setValues()`.

`getValues()` produces a 2d array which you can access with indexes (let's use integer variables `row` and `col` in our example) `data[row][col]`

So let's say you wish to set `one, two, three` to column A, B and C in row 1, then you simply have to do

```
var targetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, 1, 3)
var data = [['One', 'Two', 'Three']]
targetRamge.setValues(data)
```

Now let's say I want to write One, Two and Three into Column A over rows 1 2 and 3 then it is only slightly different:

```
var targetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, 3, 1) //we now get 1 column, but 3 rows
var data = [['One'], ['Two'], ['Three']] //Each array inside of the main array is a new row
targetRamge.setValues(data)
```

And there you have it. Simply manipulate the data as a 2D array all the time and use `.getValues()` and `.setValues()` with a range that uses multiple rows and/or columns.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful. Have you heard about [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))? This will add your array to the last row of the sheet.

```
function append() {
 var arr = ["a","b","c"]
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Entities')
 sheet.appendRow(arr)
```

}